# Spring mvc send an excel as byte array to server error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding

In our spring mvc project we simply send an .xlsx file to the server on a DTO object:

```
DtoClass {

   private String filename;
   private byte[] array;
}
```

now on the server we receive this file through a simple controller.

The problem is when we save this simple excel file on to the disk from this byte[] the file is corrupted.
Any ideas why?

p.s the client sends the byte array with  encoding using base64.
Another interesting fact - txt files actually work and can be opened regularly with a text editor after being sent from client-> server

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html).

You can either update the DTO to have `MultipartFile` as field or can send it directly.

**Approach 1** - `MultipartFile` as part of DTO

Update the DTO as below

```
DtoClass { 
    private String filename;
    private MultipartFile file;

    // getter & setters
}
```

The controller should look like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doUpload/", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public void uploadMultipart(
    final HttpServletRequest request,
    @RequestParam("file") DtoClass dto) { ... }
```

**Approach 2** - `MultipartFile` sent directly

Here your controller would look like something as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doUpload/", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public void uploadMultipart(
    final HttpServletRequest request,
    @RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile multiPartFile) { ... }
```

**P.S.**:

1. Make sure you make an entry of `<bean id="multipartResolver"        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />` in your config file.
2. Also client should set `enctype="multipart/form-data"`